# Getting a domain name, reccomended servers, etc

Tags: python, website, domain-name-system, web-hosting

Ok. I know all the programming but what I want is expert advice on how and where to register a domain name. Also I need to use a server online to host my website. I need it to allow python programs(so i can fetch info from other sites), php, mysql, etc...
Mainly I need a step by step to make my site that is hosted online from say www.genericwebhost.com/mysite to a www.mywebsite.com.

Comment: Kind of like asking "I want to create the worlds greatest program, please tell me everything I need to know to do that".

Answer (score 1):

1. Get a domain name from [a domain name registrar](http://www.icann.org/en/registrars/accredited-list.html)
2. Get [a Python-friendly web host](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonHosting)
3. Follow the host's instructions for associating the domain name with the server
4. Profit!